# Sends Data to WCF Webservice link from AJAx

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

wants to send data from Ajax to Wcf service That Contains Method GetQuickQuote(string x) and returns Data from Webservice.

Jquery

```
 $('#txtBox').blur(function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://logicalfire-pc:8090/Libertytest.Service1.svc" + "/GetQuickQuote", 
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({ x: 'ght'}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d == true) {

                    alert("You will now be redirected.");
                }

            },
            error:function(eror)
            {
                alert('failure');
            }

        })
    });
```

WCF Service Contains

```
public string GetQuickQuote(string x)
        {
            var ReadXmlPath = GetApplicationPath() + "TextFile1.txt";
x=ReadXmlPath;
    return x;


       }
```

I am Getting FOllowing Response :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://logicalfire-pc:8090/Libertytest.Service1.svc/GetQuickQuote. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your `global.asax` file in webservice

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
   {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
   }
}
```